# Set properties in gradle-wrapper.properties from the input

Tags: gradle

Is it possible to set build environment properties dynamically?

gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
...
apiKey=* api key from gradle line input args *
```

Thanks

Comment: why would you do that in `gradle-wrapper.properties`?

Comment: @Henry it's only way to do that for all projects building

Comment: typically, the wrapper and the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file are procect specific. The purpose of them is to achieve a stable per project build environment. Configuration shared bewteen all projects should go into a global gradle config file.

Comment: @Henry One reason I can think of is I want development to have a different gradle distribution type for development and a minimized one for QA/Production build. e.g. `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.9-${DIST_TYPE:bin}.zip` then on the command line: `gradlew build -DDIST_TYPE="all"` or something like that. I don't know if this would work.

Comment: No it does not work